# Quantization of Electric Charge and Cutting Spheres

Tags: electrostatics, charge, discrete

Say you have a metallic sphere that holds a charge $Q$ uniformly. If we cut the sphere into two equal halves, each half of the sphere will hold a charge of $Q/2$. Also, electric charge is quantized. That is, $Q=ne$, where $n∈\mathbb{Z}$, and e=-1.602176634×$10^{-19}$ C. Now, say that the charge on the sphere $Q$ is $3e$. What happens when we cut the sphere into two equal halves? What charge will each half hold? Clearly $3/2∉\mathbb{Z}$. I have thought about this a lot and I can't even guess as to what might happen. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how can you cut a point-like object into two, what will you use to cut it?

Comment: Who said anything about a point like object?

Comment: an electron having charge $1.6\times 10^{-19} C$ is point-like

Comment: Well yes, but I am not talking about cutting the electron. Say you have a sphere with a charge of (2n+1)e where n is a natural number. What happens then when you cut the sphere into two equal halves is my question.

Comment: Clearly an even number of electrons will go in one half of the sphere, an uneven number in the other half. Did that thought not cross your mind?

Comment: Obviously, it did, but that contradicts the fact that when a sphere carrying charge Q is cut into two equal halves, each half carries a charge of Q/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, say that the charge on the sphere Q is 3e. What happens when we cut the sphere into two equal halves? What charge will each half hold?

At the level of electrons the answer is : 2 on one half and 1 on the other, or all three on one side and zero on the other. It is the same problem as if you have a symmetric apple tree with three apples, after all, and you cut it in half, how many apples on each half?

At the level of how probable it is to have all electrons on one half and zero on the other one would need the quantum mechanical definition of the sphere, as electrons are quantum mechanical entities, controlled by probabilities given by the wavefunction of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are asking to cut an electron in half.

But an electron is an elementary particle. It cannot be so cut.

Theres nothing more to say about this.